# Divisibility question for non UFD rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime element. I need an example of a domain in which $p^n$ divides $ab$ and $p^n$ does not divide $a$ and $p$ does not divide $b$. Obviously, the domain I'm looking for is not a UFD.
Thanks

Comment: Which non-UFD domains are you familiar with? Knowing this would help answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *any* integral domain, prime products behave much as they do in UFDs. For example, their factorizations into atoms are unique. Furthermore products of primes are *primal*, namely, the *prime divisor property* $\rm\ p\ |\ ab\ \Rightarrow\ p\ |\ a\ \ or\ \ p\ |\ b\ $  generalizes from atoms to composites as follows

**Theorem** $\, $ In domain $\cal D\,,\, $ prime product $\rm\, C\mid AB\,  \Rightarrow\,  C = ab,\ a\mid A,\  b\mid B,\, $ some $\rm\ a,b\in \cal D$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on product length $\rm\,n.\,$ Trivial if $\rm\ n = 0\!:\,$ then $\rm\ C = 1\ $ so take $\rm\ a = 1 = b\,.\,$

Else $\rm\,n\ge 1\,$ so $\rm\, C = pc,\ p\,$ prime. $\rm\, C = pc\mid AB\, \Rightarrow\, p\mid A\ $ or $\rm\ p\mid B.\,$ W.l.o.g assume $\rm\ p\mid B\,$ so

$\quad \rm pc\mid AB\ \Rightarrow\ c\mid A\,(B/p)\quad $ since $\rm\ p\ne 0\ \Rightarrow\ p$ cancellable, by $\,\cal D\,$ domain

$\rm\qquad\qquad\quad\! \Rightarrow\ \ c\ =\ ab,\ \ a\mid A,\ \ b\mid B/p\quad $ by induction

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ C =  pc\ =\ abp,\ \ a\mid A,\ \ bp\mid B\quad $ **QED**

**Corollary** $\ $ In domain $\cal D\,,\ $ prime power $\rm\ p^n\mid AB,\ \ p\nmid B\ \,  \Rightarrow\  p^n\mid A$

Answer (score 3):

You can show by induction that this is impossible. For $n=1$, this is just the definition of $p$ being prime. Now assume that it is impossible for $n$ but possible for $n+1$. Let $p^{n+1}\mid ab$ but $p^{n+1}\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$. Then $ab=p^{n+1}c=p(p^nc)$, and since $p$ is prime and $p\mid ab$ and $p\nmid b$, we must have $p\mid a$, so $ab=(pd)b=p(db)$. Cancelling $p$ in $p(p^nc)=p(db)$ yields $p^nc=db$ with $p^n\nmid d$ (since $p^{n+1}\nmid a$), but this is impossible by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: when you assume that this is impossible for $n$ but possible for $n+1$ you are assuming that $p|b$ and $p \nmid b$... Again, how do you conclude that from $p^nc=db$ then necessarily $p^n \nmid  d$?

Comment: @Lmn6: I don't understand the first part of that comment. The sentence "Now assume that it is impossible for $n$ but possible for $n+1$" doesn't contain $b$. The next sentence does; it states that $a$, $b$ furnish an example of the possibility for $n+1$. What follows then deduces from this that $d$, $b$ furnish an example of the possibility for $n$, contrary to the induction hypothesis.  I don't see where I ever assumed $p|b$.

Comment: @Lmn6: I also don't understand what you mean by "again". Regarding the rest of the second part of your comment, I don't conclude $p^n\nmid d$ from $p^nc=db$; as I tried to indicate by the parenthesis "(since $p^{n+1}\nmid a$)", I conclude this from the fact that $a=pd$ and $p^{n+1}\nmid a$: if we had $p^n|d$, then $d=p^nr$, and then $a=p(p^nr)=(pp^n)r=p^{n+1}r$ and thus $p^{n+1}|a$.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you assume that is impossible for $n$ and possible for $n+1$.

Comment: @Lmn6: The existence of an example as described in your question. That is, let $A(n)$ be the assertion that there exist $p$ prime and $a$ and $b$ such that $p^n|ab$, $p^n\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$. Then $A(1)$ is false by definition of a prime element; and my argument shows that $A(n+1)$ is false if $A(n)$ is false.

Comment: The initial statement is $(p^n \mid ab \wedge p^n \nmid b)\rightarrow p \nmid b$. If $n=1$ it is not true by the def of prime element. So your argument assumes that for, say $m$ it is not valid, i.e. the following is true: $(p^m \mid ab \wedge p^m \nmid b)\wedge p \mid b$

Comment: @Lmn6: No, that statement (what you call "the initial statement") doesn't occur anywhere, neither in your question nor in my answer. What I called $A(n)$ in my comment above is $\exists p,a,b:p^n\mid ab\land p^n\nmid a\land p\nmid b$. The negation of this (in case that's what you meant) is $\forall p,a,b:\neg(p^n\mid ab\land p^n\nmid a\land p\nmid b)$, which can be rewritten as $\forall p,a,b:(p^n\mid ab\land p^n\nmid a)\to p\mid b$; note the $\mid$ where you had $\nmid$, and vice versa for your second statement.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, in my original question (then edited) I was meaning what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to joriki (who gives a perfect answer to his interpretation of the question), I interpreted $p$ in your question as an ordinary prime integer.
In that case, given indeterminates $A,B$ over $\mathbb Z$, the domain $D=\mathbb Z[a,b]=\mathbb Z[A,B]/(A\cdot B-p^n)$ has the properties you require.

[Integrity comes from irreducibility of $A\cdot B-p^n$ and  the very construction ensures that $p^n$ divides $ab=p^n$.
That $p^n$ does not divide $a$ and that $p$ does not divide $b$ can be seen by a trick: divide out the domain $D$ by the ideal $(b)$ resp. $(a)$]

Comment: Dear Georges: You have $ab=p^n$ (not $ab=0$), don't you? (+1)

Comment: I don't understand how this is a possible interpretation of the question, even if you read "prime integer" for "prime element": $p$ considered as an element of $D$ is neither a prime element (since $p\mid ab$ but $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$), nor a prime integer, since $D$ consists not of integers but of equivalence classes of polynomials with integer coefficients. In what sense can $p\in D$ be regarded as a prime element?

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves: as usual you are right. I have just corrected my stupid mistake and am very grateful to you for having spotted it: thanks a lot and Bonne Année!

Comment: Dear Georges: Thanks, and Bonne Année to you too!

Comment: Dear @joriki, my interpretation is due to the fact that $p$ was introduced in the question *before* any mention in the first sentence of a domain. So I didn't think of $p$ as a prime of $D$. But don't worry: I am quite ready to admit that your interpretation is the better one!

Comment: @Georges: Ah, I see. Yes, I'd noticed that $p$ was introduced before the domain but just put it down to inexperience in presentation. It seems that people sometimes unorthodoxly use constructions like "let $p$ be a prime element" to express something that would more orthodoxly be expressed as "In the following, the variable name $p$ will stand for a prime element of a domain", i.e. to explain what *sort* of thing a given letter will be standing for and not to introduce a certain *value* for a certain variable.

Comment: Dear @joriki: Any ring $R$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module. Thus, if $n$ is an integer, then $n\cdot1$ is an element of $R$, usually (and abusively) denoted $n$. In Georges's case, we have moreover: $n=0$ in $D$ implies $n=0$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

The following statements are straightforward and answer immediately (joriki's interpretation of) your question:

$\bullet$ If an element of your domain is of the form $p^na$ with $p\nmid a$, then the pair $(n,a)$ is unique.

$\bullet$ If two elements are of this form, so is their product.