# Is $\sqrt[2]{(2/7)}$ irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

I have to show that the $\sqrt(2/7)$ is irrational.  Here is my work.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448172/what-rational-numbers-have-rational-square-roots

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually reached a contradiction unless you've asserted at the outset that $(m,n) = 1$. But once you assert that you can stop with this line: $2n^2 = 7m^2$. If $n$ is even,  $m$ must be odd and the LHS is even, the RHS isn't. Contradiction. But if $n$ is odd and $m$ is even the LHS is an odd multiple of $2$ while the RHS is an even multiple of $2$, again leading to a contradiction.

Edited to patch a hole in the proof that I just noticed after notification of the upvote.

Comment: Any rational number is written in a fraction that's irreducible. So it's understood that gcd(m,n) = 1

Comment: @user230452 A rational number can be represented in the form $\frac ab$. That fraction may or may not be in a reduced form, and in the latter case, a and b are not coprime. But the point is that you can always reduce that fraction by cancelling out all common factors until left with 2 coprime numbers m and n. The point I was making was that if you don't start with this assertion, you will not have a valid proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You're skipping some steps.

You say that $7m^2$ is even, then you assume $m$ is even. This is true. You should say why though, you explain a little more why $n$ is even.

Also, how is the end a contradiction? You found that the gcd is even, when did you ever assume that it wasn't?

Comment: If a number where rational gcd(m,n)  equals 1.  Since this is not the case, I reached a contradiction and the number is irrational.

Comment: @Bayerischer That's not what's going on here. $\frac22$ is surely rational, but $\gcd(2,2)$ isn't $1$.

Comment: $7m^2$ can be expanded as a product of prime factors. Since, 7 cannot be reduced further. The 2 term must one from the m^2 part, which implies m is even too. The contradiction is a gcd more than 1.