# How to find if $n$th root of $m$ is rational?

Tags: radicals, decimal-expansion, rationality-testing

I know that if $m$ is an integer, then the $n$th root of $m$ must be an integer, else it is irrational. But what if $n$ and $m$ both are decimals - is there a way of easily telling if the $n$th root of $m$ is rational or irrational without actually calculating all/a lot the digits?

Comment: If $a/b$ is an irreducible fraction, then $\sqrt[m]{a/b}$ is rational iff $\sqrt[m]{a},\sqrt[m]{b}$ are integers.

Comment: See the related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448172/what-rational-numbers-have-rational-square-roots?rq=1).  Yours is a bit more general though as it sounds like you are asking for noninteger roots as well, e.g. $e^{\frac{1}{\pi}}=\sqrt[\pi]{e}$.