# Prove $\sqrt{k}$ is not a rational number.

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $k>1$ is an integer, and k is not a square number, then $\sqrt{k}$ is not a rational number.

Proof:

Let $\sqrt{k}=\frac{p}{q}$, and $(p,q)=1$,So $q^2|p^2$, $p\neq 1$, $k$ is not an integer.When $q=p=1$, and $k>1$.

And $q=1$, then $\sqrt{k}=p$, and $k$ is a square number.

I do think it's so easy...Where is wrong?

How to do it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. The English doesn't even make sense. Can you rewrite your proof carefully?

Comment: What do you mean "$k$ is not an integer"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324724/p1-n-is-irrational-if-p-is-prime-and-n1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448172/what-rational-numbers-have-rational-square-roots#comment962631_448172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: I think you started correctly, but made some odd jumps.  I'm going to offer some critique of the proof--please don't take anything here personally. `:)`

A proof is more than just a string of symbols--rather, it must be a clearly (yet concisely) written work that allows the reader a peak inside your mind when you proved the proposition.

So, I would suggest:

- Whenever you start a proof by contradiction, make sure to denote it.
- Always "introduce" your variables.  Are you assuming $k$ is an integer?  A complex number?  What about $p$ and $q$?
- Don't use notation unless it really helps.  Sometimes it's easier to say (and nearly always easier to read) "$p$ and $q$ coprime," rather than "$(p, q) = 1$".
- Show your algebra, or at least mention that you're doing some.  Don't make me think about why $\sqrt{k} = \frac{p}{q}$ implies $q^2|p^2$--show me from the definition of *divides*.

So, a start to the proof could be:

> **Proof:**
>   Assume proposition is false.  That is, there exists a $k \in \Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $k>1$ is not a perfect square and $\sqrt{k}$ is rational.
>
> As $\sqrt{k}$ is rational, there exist coprime integers $p$ and $q$ ($q\ne0$) such that:
>   $$\sqrt{k} = \frac{p}{q}$$
>
> Rearranging the above, we find that:
>   $$p = q\sqrt{k}$$
>   It follows:
>   $$p^2 = q^2k$$
>   ...