# If $p$ is prime and any integer $k>1$, then $p^{\frac 1k} $ is irrational. Prove this by assuming $p^{\frac 1k}$ rational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've tried setting $p^{\dfrac 1k}= \dfrac a b$, and then raising $p^{\dfrac 1k}$ to the $k^\text{th}$ power, but I'm stuck.

Comment: where did you get stuck? Because your idea is good!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324729/25928

Comment: Remember $p\mid nm\implies p\mid n$ or $p\mid m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $p^{\frac1k}$ be rational then $p^{\frac1k}=\frac ab$ with $(a,b)=1$ or $p=\frac {a^{k}}{b^{k}}$,

since p is a prime hence integer we have $b=1$ and $p=a^k$, and if $k>1$ then p will be divisible by more then two numbers, hence it will not be prime, a contradiction, therefore $p^{\frac1k}$ is irrational for $k>1$ and p be a prime.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality, assume that $(a,b)=1$. If $a^k = p b^k$ then what can you say about $a$ (and then, using $k \geqslant 2$, about $b$)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $p^{1/k}=\frac{a}{b}$is in lowest terms.  Taking $k$-th powers and rewriting gives: $b^kp=a^k$.  By the funamental theorem of arithmetic the prime factorization of any positive integer is unique.  Now note that the number of times $p$ appears on the left hand side will be more than the number of times it is on the right hand side.  This violates this uniqueness.