# Show the indivisibility $\,xy\nmid x^2+y^2\,$ if $\, \gcd(x,y)= 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are an integer $x,y$ where $\gcd(x,y)=1$ show the indivisibility of $\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$ where $x \neq y \neq 1$

I tried to transform $\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=\frac{(x+y)^2-2xy}{xy}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}-2$

but I don't know if it is a good direction.

Comment: $$(x^2+y^2,y)=(x^2,y)=1$$ as $(x,y)=1$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few sketched proofs, by $(1)$ Unique Factorization, $(2)$ Euclid's Lemma, $(3)$ Bezout's Lemma.

$(1)\,\ \ \ \rm \color{#0A0}{prime}\ p\mid\color{#C00}{x\mid xy\mid x^2\!+y^2}\Rightarrow\, p\mid y^2 \color{#0A0}\Rightarrow\: p\mid y\,\Rightarrow\: p\mid(x,y)=1\,\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

$(2)\,\ \ \ \rm\color{#C00}{x\mid xy\mid  x^2\!+y^2} \,\Rightarrow\, x\mid y^2\:$ contra $\,\ \rm (x,y)=1 \overset{Euclid}\Rightarrow (x,y^2) = 1$

$(3)\,\ \ \rm\ 1\! \overset{Bezout}=\! (ax\!+\!by)^2 = (a^2\!-b^2)\color{#C00}x^2\!+b^2\color{#C00}{(x^2\!+y^2)}+2ab\color{#C00}xy,\,$  so $\rm\ \color{#C00}{x\mid rhs}\, \Rightarrow\ x\mid lhs\!=\!1\, \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

**Remark** $\, (2)$ and $(3)$ are in fact equivalent to the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations of integers. These and many other such equivalent properties are listed in [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322046)

Comment: I'm so happy you came back! ;-)

Comment: What does "contra" mean? And what is $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$? And welcome back!

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks. They mean "contradicting" and "contradiction", respectively. The first is [standard English](http://www.google.com/search?q=contra+define) and the second (opposing arrows) is one of the [common symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction#Symbolic_representation) used to denote that a contradiction has been reached.

Comment: @BillDubuque: you might have crossed paths with someone who dislikes people with higher reputations answering easier questions. I don't know; this question is on the upper border of LHF.

Comment: hey, christmas colors! how appropriate.

Comment: @Alex I wait with $\rm\color{#c00}{bated}\ \color{#0a0}{\TeX} $ for a question on [Fermat's Christmas Theorem!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) $\ $

Comment: Welcome back Bill!!! Was waiting for this day :)

Answer (score 3):

By Euclid's Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), since $x\nmid x^2 + y^2$ since $x\nmid y$, and similarly $y\nmid x^2 + y^2$, then $xy\nmid x^2 + y^2$

Comment: I changed \not{|} to \nmid.  Notice that 3|6 looks different from 3\mid 6: $3|6$ versus $3\mid6$. The latter is standard. ${{}\qquad{}}$