# Let $a, b, n$ be elements of $\mathbb N $ such that $ a^n\mid b^n $. Show that $a\mid b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, n$ be elements of $\mathbb N$ such that $ a^n\mid b^n $. Show that $a\mid b$.

[P.S. Use the axioms of natural numbers.]

Are we using the properties of divisibility and afterwards induction? I kind of have an idea but I am not quite sure.

Comment: If you use the unique factorisation theorem, it follows pretty smoothly.

Comment: i am not allowed to use the unique factorization theorem,because i also thought of using that @user88595

Comment: You have zero accept answers so far. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: To prove this normally requires using something that is essentially equivalent to uniqueness of prime factorizations (e.g. see the many equivalents [listed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322046)). Do you have any of these available? If not, you will need to prove one of them (or, essentially, inline their (inductive) proofs in your proof).

Comment: If you kind of have an idea, you should include the details, so that we know how to effectively help you.

Comment: All of the divisibility theorems + Bezu's theorem are allowed to be used?How can i connect them with the question more concretely?@BillDubuque

Comment: @d.i... Bezout's theorem immediately yields Euclid's Lemma, which immediately yields the Rational Root Test. It also immediately yields the Prime Divisor Property $\, p\mid ab\Rightarrow p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b,\,$ which yields *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. Thus, from Bezout, you can quickly deduce the results needed in either my answer or Michael's.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ (b/a)^n  = k \in \Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ b/a\in \Bbb Z\ $ by the  [Rational Root Test,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) i.e. if $\,x\,$ is a rational root of  the polynomial $\rm \,\color{#c00}1\cdot x^n-k\,$ then its least-terms denominator divides $\color{#c00}1,\,$ so $\,x\,$ is an integer.

Comment: From a foundational perspective (and possibly relevant to the OP's class), it's interesting to consider how the rational root test compares to the uniqueness of prime factorizations. The proof of the rational root test uses two number theory facts: (1) if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then so are $a$ and $b^n$; (2) if $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a$ divides $bc$, then $a$ divides $c$. Both of these can be proved from Bézout's identity alone, without using prime factorizations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot…\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}=a$, $q_1^{\beta_1}\cdot…\cdot q_m^{\beta_m}=b$ be prime decompositions. Then $a^n=p_1^{n\alpha_1}\cdot…\cdot p_k^{n\alpha_k}$, $b^n=q_1^{n\beta_1}\cdot…\cdot q_m^{n\beta_m}$. Now write up what $a^n|b^n$ means in term of prime powers.

Comment: OP is not allowed here to use the unique factorization theorem. See her comments.